# SwiftUI hides titlebar and causes the NSScrollView line to be lost

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm writing my MacOS app with SwiftUI, and I have a special need to hide the window title.

So my basic code is:

```
@main
struct MailApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle()) // here hide titleBar
    }
}
```

However, in doing so, I will encounter a problem, that is, after my sidebar rolls, there is no horizontal line that should appear at the top.

[image]

If I didn't use `.windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())`, it would look like this.

[image]

I tried `.presentedWindowStyle(DefaultWindowStyle())` to restore the titlebar of the current window, but it didn't work.

like this

```
@main
struct MailApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
            .presentedWindowStyle(DefaultWindowStyle()) // here add
        }
        .windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle()) // here hide titleBar
    }
}
```

So now I have two questions:

1. Why doesn't the `.presentedWindowStyle(DefaultWindowStyle())` work.
2. How to hide the titlebar so that there is this horizontal line visually?

PS:
I've seen "Debug View Hierarchy" in Xcode, but it doesn't seem special. I see NSScrollView wrapped up as a new private object. I can find the NSScrollView through the code, but I don't know how to set it to the original style.

thx.

Comment: It is not a line it is shadow of titlebar, as you removed it - there is no shadow. You can add it manually above your List.

Comment: @Asperi "You can add it manually above your List." How to do this? pls